# Custom UIButton from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

I create `Button` in storyboard and select type `Custom` for `iOS 7.0` it change `titleColor`(highlighted work), but for `iOS 6.0` when I touch it show only titleColor for state normal (highlighted does not work).

Also I tried to change it programmatically:

```
[self.myBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm using Xcode `5.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write code as below:

```
[self.myBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.myBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: It is wrong, because `UIControlStateHighlighted` don't call for ios 6.0 and when I touch my button titleColor will be that I selected in storyboard